# Want to use same data provider but different excel path for different functions to provide data in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, dataprovider, data-driven

Want to use same DataProvider to provide data to multiple methods. Have created utility using Apache POI to read excel File and parameterized it and using data provider im sending data to the application.

Data Provider provides the data to one of the methods but using same data provider I want to provide data to another method but with different excel path. In short, parameterized the path. How to do it?

````
    public Object [][] logindetails() {
        configexcel datas= new configexcel("C:\\Users\\xyz.xlsx"); //configexcel class
        int rows= datas.rowsncol(0);
        int col= datas.column(0);
        Object [][] data= new Object[rows-1][col];
        for(int i=1;i<rows;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<col;j++) {
                 data[i-1][j]= datas.readdata(0,i,j);
        }
        return data;
    }
  

--configexcel datas= new configexcel("C:\\Users\\xyz.xlsx"); //want to parameterize this.

//Constructor

package excelconfig;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class configexcel {
    
    XSSFWorkbook loadwb;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    
    public configexcel(String excelpath) {
        
        try {
            File src=new File(excelpath);
            FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream(src);
            loadwb= new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("The error is"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
        public String readdata(int sheets,int row,int col) {
            
            sheet=loadwb.getSheetAt(sheets);
            String inputs=sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();
            return inputs;  
        }
        
        public int rowsncol(int rows) {
            int count=loadwb.getSheetAt(rows).getLastRowNum();
            count=count+1;
            return count;
        }
        
        public int column(int col) {
            sheet= loadwb.getSheetAt(0);
            int counts= sheet.getRow(col).getLastCellNum();
            // counts=counts+1;
            return counts;
        }```

}
````

Answer (score 0):

Use excel reader in selenium and store data fields in your code and do parameterization

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {
    public String path;
    public FileInputStream fis = null;
    public FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    private XSSFRow row = null;
    private XSSFCell cell = null;

    public ExcelReader(String path) {

        this.path = path;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // returns the row count in a sheet

    public int getRowCount(String sheetName) {
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if (index == -1)
            return 0;
        else {
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            int number = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
            return number;
        }

    }
    // returns the data from a cell
    public String getCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum) {
        try {
            if (rowNum <= 0)
                return "";

            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
            int col_Num = -1;
            if (index == -1)
                return "";

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                // System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
                if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                    col_Num = i;
            }
            if (col_Num == -1)
                return "";

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
            if (row == null)
                return "";
            cell = row.getCell(col_Num);

            if (cell == null)
                return "";

            //System.out.println(cell.getCellType().name());
            //
            if (cell.getCellType().name().equals("STRING"))
                return cell.getStringCellValue();

                // if (cell.getCellType().STRING != null)

                // if(cell.getCellType()==Xls_Reader.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                // return cell.getStringCellValue();
            else if ((cell.getCellType().name().equals("NUMERIC")) || (cell.getCellType().name().equals("FORMULA"))) {

                String cellText = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    // format in form of M/D/YY
                    double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                    cellText = (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                    cellText = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "/" + cellText;

                    // System.out.println(cellText);

                }

                return cellText;
            } else if (cell.getCellType().BLANK != null)
                return "";
            else
                return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row " + rowNum + " or column " + colName + " does not exist in xls";
        }
    }


    // returns the data from a cell
    public String getCellData(String sheetName, int colNum, int rowNum) {
        try {
            if (rowNum <= 0)
                return "";

            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);

            if (index == -1)
                return "";

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
            if (row == null)
                return "";
            cell = row.getCell(colNum);
            if (cell == null)
                return "";

            //
            if (cell.getCellType().name().equals("STRING"))
                return cell.getStringCellValue();

                //
                // if (cell.getCellType().STRING != null)
                // return cell.getStringCellValue();
            else if ((cell.getCellType().name().equals("NUMERIC")) || (cell.getCellType().name().equals("FORMULA"))) {

                String cellText = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    // format in form of M/D/YY
                    double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                    cellText = (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                    cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cellText;

                    // System.out.println(cellText);

                }

                return cellText;
            } else if (cell.getCellType().BLANK != null)
                return "";
            else
                return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row " + rowNum + " or column " + colNum + " does not exist  in xls";
        }
    }

    // returns true if data is set successfully else false
    public boolean setCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data) {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            if (rowNum <= 0)
                return false;

            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
            int colNum = -1;
            if (index == -1)
                return false;

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                // System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
                if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
                    colNum = i;
            }
            if (colNum == -1)
                return false;

            sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
            row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
            if (row == null)
                row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);

            cell = row.getCell(colNum);
            if (cell == null)
                cell = row.createCell(colNum);

            // cell style
            // CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
            // cs.setWrapText(true);
            // cell.setCellStyle(cs);
            cell.setCellValue(data);

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

            workbook.write(fileOut);

            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // returns true if sheet is created successfully else false
    public boolean addSheet(String sheetname) {

        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            workbook.createSheet(sheetname);
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // returns true if sheet is removed successfully else false if sheet does
    // not exist
    public boolean removeSheet(String sheetName) {
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if (index == -1)
            return false;

        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // returns true if column is created successfully
    public boolean addColumn(String sheetName, String colName) {
        // System.out.println("**************addColumn*********************");

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
            if (index == -1)
                return false;

            XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            // style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
            // style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

            row = sheet.getRow(0);
            if (row == null)
                row = sheet.createRow(0);

            // cell = row.getCell();
            // if (cell == null)
            // System.out.println(row.getLastCellNum());
            if (row.getLastCellNum() == -1)
                cell = row.createCell(0);
            else
                cell = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum());

            cell.setCellValue(colName);
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    // removes a column and all the contents
    public boolean removeColumn(String sheetName, int colNum) {
        try {
            if (!isSheetExist(sheetName))
                return false;
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            // style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
            XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            // style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.NO_FILL);
            for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(sheetName); i++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                if (row != null) {
                    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        cell.setCellStyle(style);
                        row.removeCell(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    // find whether sheets exists
    public boolean isSheetExist(String sheetName) {
        int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if (index == -1) {
            index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName.toUpperCase());
            if (index == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    // returns number of columns in a sheet
    public int getColumnCount(String sheetName) {
        // check if sheet exists
        if (!isSheetExist(sheetName))
            return -1;

        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
        row = sheet.getRow(0);

        if (row == null)
            return -1;

        return row.getLastCellNum();

    }

    public int getCellRowNum(String sheetName, String colName, String cellValue) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= getRowCount(sheetName); i++) {
            if (getCellData(sheetName, colName, i).equalsIgnoreCase(cellValue)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }

}
```

Comment: ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader("path excel sheet ");

Comment: Appreciate your quick response.This code reads different sheets and writes in different file(sheet) and validations. Actually, I have created the constructor to getRow, getCell, etc from the excel file and created an array (code provided) to store and provide data to a function. The problem is when I parameterize the path in constructor and pass an argument(path) in the dataprovider, I'm able to use the dataprovider ONLY ONCE whereas I want to use the dataprovider multiple times for different functions by providing different excel WORKBOOK path, depending on the functional data requirement.

Comment: did you try above  util class ?

Comment: I used part of the code only to read, not write into sheet